# get id from drop-down select tag to put into link

Tags: php, hyperlink, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down select tag for Patients:

```
<select>
<?php
$qPatient = mysql_query("SELECT idpatients, firstName, mi, lastName, suffix FROM patients ORDER BY lastName ASC");  

while($rowPatient = mysql_fetch_array( $qPatient )) {
if(isset($rowPatient['suffix']) && !empty($rowPatient['suffix'])){$suffix = " " . $rowPatient['suffix'];}else{$suffix = NULL;}
            if(isset($rowPatient['mi']) && !empty($rowPatient['mi'])){$mi = " " . $rowPatient['mi'] . ".";}else{$mi = NULL;}
            echo "<option value=" . $rowPatient['idpatients'] . $rowPatient . ">" . $rowPatient['lastName'] . $suffix . ", " . $rowPatient['firstName'] . $mi . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This generates a list of patients from the drop-down.
How do I get the patientID based on the selection from my drop-down to put to my link?

ex: `<a href="update.php?patientID=$idpatients">Update</a>`

where $idpatients = the patient ID from the drop-down list select tag.

Also, I need to have 3 different links: 1.) update.php 2.) chart.php and 3.) report.php

Answer (score 1):

Set this form method to GET. After submiting, value of select field will be shown as get variable. So, add name to your select:

```
<select name="parientId">
```

And proper action to your form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="GET">
```

And, of course submit button.

This is "static way" with form". If you are sure that you want to have link, not submit button, you can do it with jQuery:

```
$("#go").click(function(){ $("#idOfYourForm").submit(); }
...
<a href="" id="go">Go !</a>
```

Or catch `.change()` (sorry, not select()) on your `<select...>` and set `$("#go").attr('href','update.php?patientId='+$("#yourSelectId").val());`

P.S.
Get from SQL only fields you need, not *

**Update**

```
<form...>
<select name="patientId" id="patientSelect">
...
</select>
<a id="updatelink" href="">....</a>
<a id="deletelink" href="">....</a>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#patientSelect").change(function(){
    $("#updatelink").attr('href',"update.php?id="+$("#parientSelect").val());
    $("#deletelink").attr('href',"delete.php?id="+$("#parientSelect").val());
  }
});
</script>
```

Something like that, written fast, not checked/tested

Comment: I forgot to mention that I plan to have multiple links. Like if I select John Doe from the list, I have 3 links to choose from. Update.php, Report.php, Chart.php I updated the code to run mySql faster with the fields I only need :)

Comment: i think the last part (.select()) is what I need to try. What's the whole code for it?

Comment: Remeber that you can do it simple - have seweral submit buttons with different names/values, and check in PHP wich one was posted (0 javascript).

Comment: I put your code, but it looks like it's not working and Dreamweaver says "There is a syntax error on line... Code hinting may not work untlil you fix this error. The line with error is @ at the end "});</script>. The reason why I wanted a regular text link, because of the menu style that I have. :) PS: I also change "#patientSelect" to "#patientSelect", but error still shows up.

Comment: i got error out of the way, because missing an extra closing parenthesis ")". But link "update.php?id.." is not working