# How do I put id number from select tag to a php link?

Tags: php, javascript

[image][image]Currently, this is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
<form>
<select name="patientID" id="patientSelect">
<?php
$qPatient = mysql_query("SELECT idpatients, firstName, mi, lastName, suffix FROM patients ORDER BY lastName ASC");  

while($rowPatient = mysql_fetch_array( $qPatient )) {
if(isset($rowPatient['suffix']) && !empty($rowPatient['suffix'])){$suffix = " " . $rowPatient['suffix'];}else{$suffix = NULL;}
            if(isset($rowPatient['mi']) && !empty($rowPatient['mi'])){$mi = " " . $rowPatient['mi'] . ".";}else{$mi = NULL;}
            echo "<option value=" . $rowPatient['idpatients'] . $rowPatient . ">" . $rowPatient['lastName'] . $suffix . ", " . $rowPatient['firstName'] . $mi . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<a id="updatelink" href="">....</a>
<a id="deletelink" href="">....</a>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#patientSelect").change(function(){
    $("#updatelink").attr('href',"update.php?id="+$("#patientSelect").val());
    $("#deletelink").attr('href',"delete.php?id="+$("#patientSelect").val());
  });
});
</script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/Euyzp/

Changing the dropdown's value changes the href of the links. Are you wanting to change the links text as well?

Also just a side note, you shouldn't be wrapping that code in a $(document).ready(), because you want that script to execute as soon as the `<select>` is added to the DOM.

Comment: i update the question with screenshot to show that the javascript is not changing the link :(

Comment: @Arnold Porche Villaluz

Have you checked your generated HTML source to make sure that `$rowPatient['idpatients']` is showing up correctly in the `<option value="">`? As you can see from the jsfiddle, your javascript does work. I think you might have a PHP or MySQL error.

Comment: yes i did. value shows correctly. i updated with extra screenshot of output source code

Comment: @Arnold Porche Villaluz Can you paste all your outputted code between `<select>` and `</select>` into my jsfiddle and hit update?

Comment: @Arnold Porche Villaluz, Oh my godness haha, I think I just figured out what your error is. You're not including jQuery anyways in your source code :) Try adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` into your `<head>` tag

Comment: it finally work!! wow! well I got that javascript code from this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758855/get-id-from-drop-down-select-tag-to-put-into-link and he didn't respond back when I said it wasn't working. Thank you so much PaulPRO!

Answer (score 1):

You see, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/Deele/A35B8/

Comment: i attached a screenshot with code+output to show that javascript is not working for me :(